# M3 API Toolkit ? unable to find

Tags: windows-mobile-6.5

M3 API Toolkit ? unable to find. I want to scan rfid from M3 mobile and want to show it in the text field of the browser based application by using M3 API Toolkit  !!! Need Help?

Answer (score 1):

I am not familar and never used these devices, but a simple google search and with the help of the M3 Orange (I assume this is your device) manual and web.archive.org I was able to find the site for SDK downloads: http://itc.m3mobile.net/. I did not register but you will find the SDK there.

The [manual](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3abAAQ8ToB9poJ%3awww.m3mobile.net/products/download.asp?align=0&no=425&gbn=Product%2520Manual%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&lr=lang_en%7Clang_de#37) mentions http://support.m3mobile.co.kr/ as SDK download site (see section 4.1.1). But this site seems to be down. So I started a request at web.archive.org and found the last update was in 2012: http://web.archive.org/web/20120707032116/http://support.m3mobile.co.kr/. This last update shows the new site address is **http://itc.m3mobile.net/**

You see, if one really tries, he/she can find the resources. OTOH the first I had tried to contact M3 Mobile and not experts exchange!

Answer (score 0):

This year 2017, the SDK can't be found anywhere from josef's links.

I found the SDK from [Warp Systems Downloads Section](http://www.warp.com.au/category.paje;jsessionid=skoddpwpg6xu1rz2s3vtlyzsq?CATEGORY_ID=700#q21). I'm not sure if this is official and the latest version, but it runs fine on our M3 Orange device.

Having been suggested to make our custom app call on the device's RFID methods w/o the SDK (coz we didn't purchase it), I inquired a lot from communities if this is  humanely possible. Then helpful people from Core RFID (http://www.corerfid.com/contact-us/) hinted that M3's SDK is free for download, and after a few google search queries I found that download site.

I hope this info will be helpful for someone, somewhere, some other time.

Comment: Hi, this is a pretty old topic but do you have by any chance a new link to download this sdk ? the link you gave seems to be down ...